# Move macro from one document to another

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I created a macro in vba that makes life easier for my users. Problem is that I don't know how to port this macro so that more people can use it.

Does anyone know an easy way to move a vba macro from one file to another?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the the module in the project explorer pane and specify **Export File...**

Answer (score 1):

Save the original workbook as an .XLA (excel add-in) -- note that you need to save the file on a public share drive / public network location... Then on each target computer (in excel) go to Options->Addins-> and finally add the add-in. Now the file has all of the addins / public functions.....